# Django's collectstatic is no longer copying files

Tags: django

On a project that has been deploying just fine, I am suddenly getting `0 static files copied` from `manage.py collectstatic`. I have tried wiping out the destination files in `STATIC_ROOT` and still nothing gets copied. I am not aware of any changes in the settings, on the servers, or in my fabric deployment script (but clearly **something** changed!). The user running the command owns the repo directory and destination directory.

I've verified that `manage.py findstatic` outputs the correct directory and can find the original files. If I run `FileSystemFinder.list()` from the prompt, it finds all of my static files. When I use `manage.py runserver` the images show up, so clearly they can be found.

Any ideas on what might be causing the problem?

According to the debug toolbar, the following settings are active:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/realfood/static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('css', '/var/repos/realfood/realfood/static/css'),
    ('img', '/var/repos/realfood/realfood/static/img'),
    ('js', '/var/repos/realfood/realfood/static/js'),
    ('pdf', '/var/repos/realfood/realfood/static/pdf'))
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder')
```

Comment: did you change the storage type. or introduce compress, or pipeline ?

Comment: No, that's what's so weird. I've been using django-compressor for the last year (so the Finder is not new) and didn't change the storage type.

Comment: any software updates, etc ? Django compressor is no longer supported. You might want to consider moving to django-pipeline

Comment: Finally found it: I'm hosting on Rackspace and was using django-cumulus. There was a bug in the last release (1.0.8) that didn't crop up in my deployment until yesterday. The lastest pull from the repo fixes the problem. Also, it looks like django-compressor is still supported (update 5 days ago), but moving to django-pipeline is in my queue of things to do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a specific problem with [django-cumulus](https://github.com/richleland/django-cumulus) version 1.0.8. It overrides `collectstatic` but failed to return a value. It's fixed by applying a more recent [commit](https://github.com/richleland/django-cumulus/commit/b8d8ac842f0c22607a32995a48180261d6a84c39).

Comment: This mad my day too. Have been struggling with this for some time and didn't realize it was due to this. Recently removed the dependency from an external_apps folder and moved it to our requirements.txt, probably upgraded it in the process.